# Conflict codeigniter projects in child dir

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have project where i have deploy two Codeigniter projects.

```
Root: 
   application
   system
   mail
      application
      system
```

The first page for mail is working fine but inner pages not works. 
Parent codeigniter project think that we are accessing its pages:

```
http://voteformyhero.com/mail/login/welcome
return 404 Error
http://voteformyhero.com/mail
```

work fine

**Fixed**

- I have fix this by moving mail dir into sub domain.Now mail is sub domain and works fine.

Comment: your root `.htaccess` is probably blocking you from accessing that directory. is this HMVC?

Comment: I have fix this by moving mail dir into sub domain.Now mail is sub domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tutorial if you prefer having [two applications sharing the same CodeIgniter system.](https://philsturgeon.uk/blog/2009/07/Create-an-Admin-panel-with-CodeIgniter/)